# Getting useful data from the header

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, header

I am asking this question mainly out of curiosity.
Let's say that I have a file "myFile.dat" made of a header of 10 lines and then some data from a sensor (4 columns, 10k rows).

To read the actual data, I use the loadtxt function from numpy, skipping the header:

```
import numpy as np

e = np.loadtxt("myFile.dat", skiprows=10)
localTemperature = e[:,1]
```

The header is always formatted in the same way:

> File xxxxx.dat
>
> Author ....
>
> Copyright ....
>
> Recorded on ../../..
>
> Firmware version ....
>
> Sensor version ....
>
> Location ....
>
> Battery status ....
>
> **Room Temperature: 25 +/- 0.5**
>
> Other stuff ....

Let's say that I want to access the Room Temperature: I will have to **open again** the file and read it line by line until I find "Room Temperature: ", because the header is not in the read data (I have used skiprows).

Having said that, I was wondering if there is any better way of doing this all at once.

Thank you very much,

M

Comment: Check this, if its useful in your case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310554/creating-a-dictionary-from-text-file-python-numpy

Comment: How about reading the file into memory first, splitting the header and the body, and then use `numpy.fromstring` to generate the array and extract whatever you need from the header?

Comment: What's so bad about doing your own read of those lines?  `loadtxt` isn't doing anything special or fast.

Comment: `loadtxt` accepts an already opened file.

Comment: I did not know that `loadtxt` could work on a pre-opened file, this solved my problem. Many thanks @hpaulj !

Comment: You just opened me a new world! Thank you very much, I will totally use the `fromstring()` method! @ThomasKühn